# Modeling of a special form of the precedence constraint

Tags: mathematical-modeling, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

<sub>[Crossposted](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/10541) at Operations Research SE</sub>

---

There exists a scheduling problem in which some tasks should be processed on some resources. Additionally, each task needs to be assigned to a specific position on each resource. Let the decision variable $x_{j,p,m}$ take the value $1$ if task $j$ is being assigned to position $p$ on the resource $m$, otherwise $0$. Also, one of the limitations on the model is a precedence constraint that defines as a precedence graph $G(V, E)$ in which tasks are nodes and relations are edges. ($(i \rightarrow j)$ means task $i$ should be processed before task $j$). As the problem is large-scale it is separated into two models. The following constraints are some of the parts of the first model.

\begin{align}
\sum_{p,m} x_{j,p,m} = 1 && \forall j \in J && (1)\\
\sum_{j} x_{j,p,m} \leq 1 && \forall p \in P, m \in M && (2)\\
\end{align}

The first ensures assigning each task to each position, and the second for occupying positions. The above constraints have ***integrality property*** and we are willing to keep that.

I was wondering if, is there any precedence constraint, MIP formulation, that follows this integrality property? If NO, is there any form that being as tight as possible?

P.S: the sequence of tasks is based on the position. And by position I mean the order in the machine assignments.

Comment: cross-posted [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10541/modeling-of-a-special-form-of-the-precedence-constraint).